# Can I use Xbox live gold from a different account onto another?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I have a roommate who has purchased xbox live gold, and we share the same console to play our games, but with our own accounts. Is it possible for us to share the benefits of his membership, or do I have to purchase an entirely new card for myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Xbox One you will get all of the benefits between both accounts with only one Xbox Live Gold subscription. It's called Xbox Live Home Gold and its exclusive to the Xbox One although the Xbox 360 had similar but more limited functionality.

[Source](http://www.polygon.com/2013/8/9/4605820/xbox-one-home-gold)

Comment: can confirm that this works, i have an account with xbox live on my xbox one, my brother has no xbox live on his account but is able to play online alone on my console.